# Step-by-step booting with systemd

Tags: boot, systemd, debug

It may be duplicate of someone's question. If so I'm sorry, couldn't find answer.

I'm mastering a very specific OS, based on Ubuntu server. I couldn't install OS on this hardware, so I set all system /bin and /sbin and so on on my computer. Then I compiled and install the kernel and made intramfs. Finally I copy everything from /etc directory to my computer and tried to boot it. To my surprise the kernel and initramfs pass booting pretty well, but systemd stuck at some servis or something like this.

Is it any way for debuging systemd booting process? I want manually approve from terminal avery step of booting process. Is it it possible?

Comment: This very specific os is?

Comment: "I want manually approve from terminal avery step of booting process. Is it it possible?" No.

Comment: @ubashu doesn't matter.  I want to know if it is possible turn systemd in interactive regime, so it will ask permission to run every step.

Comment: @rth the answer remains: No.

Comment: @muru why? It's a bit strange,  that systemd developers did consider debuging

Comment: @rth if they wanted to debug it, they'd use a debugger, not create a way to make it ask for confirmation for everything.

Comment: @muru not sure. initd  guys did this. If there is no way to debug booting with systemd we should ask them to add, shouldn't we?

Comment: @rth they certainly have ways to debug booting with systemd. None of them involve confirming every step. There's an option to confirm starting other processes, but I doubt that applies to things like activating the network, or mounting filesystems.

Comment: @muru Please post this option as a possibe answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [how to debug systemd problems](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_debug_Systemd_problems), the following boot option might be of interest:

> **systemd.confirm_spawn**=
>   Takes a boolean argument. If true asks for confirmation when spawning
>   processes. ( Defaults to false )

Comment: although your first two answers were incorrect, the third one works and works pretty well. Thank you. ;)